# NextJS send ID through <Link as=""> to server

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've a post object like this:

```
{
id: 1,
slug: 'hello-world'
content: '...'
}
```

Using NextJS, I'm trying to create a `Post` page that can be shown using `post/<slug>` instead of `post/<id>` so my URLs are more user friendly:

```html
<Link prefetch href={`post/${id}`} as={`post/${slug}`}>
    ...
</Link>
```

So the idea is that I can send the `id` property as defined in the `href`.

But, instead of doing that, I receive the `slug` property.

My custom server's code to deal with it is:

```
server.get('/post/:id', (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = '/post';
    const queryParams = { id: req.params.id };
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
});
```

A `console.log(req.params)` shows :

`{id: 'hello-world'}`

instead of

`{id: 1}`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Don't do so because it wouldn't work if you do SSR (if you access the page from the url bar instead of using `Link`)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you, do you mean that it's not possible or it means that I shouldn't do it?

Comment: you shouldn't do it.

Comment: also what you are doing cause a ssr that's why it doesn't work